# Error in adding option dynamically via AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with select which the options are generated dynamically. However I encounter error after adding the form id in ng-model. Would someone please pinpoint my mistakes? It works without the form.

In controller.js

```
$scope.form.colors = [
    {name:'Select Colors', value:''},
];

$http.get( url + 'color.php').success(function(data){
    for(var a=0; a < data.length; ++a){
        $scope.form.colors.push({name: data[a]['c'], value: data[a]['rid']});   
    }       
});

$scope.form.color = $scope.form.colors[0];
```

In .html

```
<div class="item item-input item-select">
  <div class="input-label">
      Color
  </div>
  <select ng-model="form.color" ng-options="c.name for c in form.colors"></select>
</div>
```

It worked initially without the `form`.

Comment: What is the issue?  What is happening that isn't correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `$scope.form` exist before you assign colors to it?

If not, you should define it like this:

```
$scope.form = {
  colors: [
    {name:'Select Colors', value:''},
  ]
};
```

The `form` object needs to exist before you can assign anything to it.